# Beringia - history of the region, periods of sea level fall/rise - paleogeography of Pleistocene

Tags: sea-level, ice-age, paleogeography

I am trying to find any published (not wiki) source of information about how many times and when exactly the Bering Land Mass was free of water. Everything that I find is just pieces of information in different papers, one contradicting another. Is there any source that can be cited reliably in scientific literature with a timeline or something like a summary table?

Comment: If somebody is interested - here is a helpful paper https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v382/n6586/abs/382060a0.html

I would like to find something similar but with more information on geography and maybe something newer...

Comment: if you are satisfied with your proposed answer, you are welcome to change its status to answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am answering to myself:
here are the papers, everything is in there

https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v423/n6942/full/nature01690.html

https://www.nature.com/ngeo/journal/v3/n2/full/ngeo729.html